# CUPS: '/usr/lib/cups/backend/usb': No such file or directory - Missing/deleted

Tags: usb, printing, cups

`/usr/lib/cups/backend/usb` does not exist anymore on my Ubuntu 16.04 LTS Xenial Xerus system.  I cannot explain why.  None of my two printers work anymore because of this.

Anyone can tell me how to create/reinstall this binary?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

hplip wasn't installed anymore on my system.  Not sure why.  I do have automatic updates configured on my Ubuntu 16.04 LTS Xenial Xerus server; maybe there was a problem and the package was dropped.

To fix the problem, I ran:

```
apt install --reinstall hplip
```

And now, both printers, *HP LaserJet 6L* and *Brother MFC J615W* work again.

Answer (score 1):

I got the same issue with my Canon printer. I don't really know what happened but re-installing cups did the trick:

```
sudo apt remove cups
sudo apt install cups
```